# Variable number of command line arguments in C++

Tags: c++, arguments

I have a program (`myprogram`) that takes a file for input and creates another file for output. The syntax is:

`myprogram inputfile outputfile`

It looks something like this:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
...  
if ( argc != 3 ) {
    cout<<"wrong number of arguments"<< endl; return 1;}
   }
myInputFile = argv[1];
myOutputFile = argv[2];
...
}
```

So here I have `argv[1]` being the inputfile.I would now like to add some options to the syntax.  So, for example, I would like `myprogram -a inputfile outputfile` as an option. The number of options will vary.

That means that the filenames will depend on the number of arguments.

What is the smartest way to do this in the code? I can see that one would just take the last two arguments as the filenames and then assume that the arguments before that are the options (so something like `myInputFile = argv[argc - 1]`. This doesn't quite feel right because I end up with a lot of `if ... then` statements.

So my question is: How does one best deal with a variable number of arguments?

Comment: If you are running your code on a Unix based system, take a look at getopt http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that in case you do not want to use libraries:

```
char* myInputFile = NULL ;
char* myOutputFile = NULL ;
bool  option_a = false ;
int   argi = 1 ;

while ( argi < argc )
{
   const char* args = argv[ argi++ ] ;

   switch ( *args )
   {
      case '-' : /* option/switch */
         if ( strcmp( args, "-a" ) == 0 )
            option_a = true ;
         else
         {
            std::cerr << "Unknow option " << args << "\n" ;
            exit( 1 ) ;
         }
         break ;

      default :
         if ( myInputFile == NULL )
            myInputFile = args ;
         else if ( myOutputFile == NULL )
            myOutputFile = args ;
         else
         {
            std::cerr << "Unexpected argument " << args << "\n" ;
            exit( 1 );
         }
         break ;
   }
}
```

At the end, when you process all your arguments you can do some final checking like, for example, testing if the input file and output file were set:

```
if ( myInputFile == NULL )
{
    std::cerr << "Input file missing!\n" ;
    exit( 1 ) ;
}
...
```

You could also put all your arguments into a structure instead of having them separately:

```
struct options_t
{
    char* myInputFile ;
    char* myOutputFile ;
    bool  option_a ;

    options_t() : myInputFile(), myOutputFile(), option_a() {}
} ;
```

This way you can pass all arguments down to your functions instead of listing them one by one.

Just a thought...

Comment: This looks like what I want. I will have to study it. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas - This is basic approach. Using a library are also great suggestions. The code above may not compile due to syntax errors. You are invited to edit my post in case you find them.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see what you are saying here and it is definitely better than what I had been thinking. I will have to spend some more time of all this to see what works best though.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way is to write a special method for handling the command line arguments. You give it `argc` and `argv` and it returns a structured set of data values. e.g.

```
struct commands
{
    char* InputFile;
    char* OutputFile;
    bool WhateverAMeans;
};
```

This way your main loop has a sufficient list of things it requires and doesn't require tons of loops.

Typically your method would use a for loop to iterate over the arguments to fill in the commands.

Alternatively there exist helper classes that do this work for you, although I cannot recommend any having not done this in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind I'd suggest a library that deals w/ all these issues. Try [Boost.Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html). It might look too complex than you expected but it's powerful enough. Also there're a lot *C* libraries, like getopt, popt and many others

Answer (score 1):

Look at boost::program_options, very useful and clean tool for that.
I also used Poco::OptionSet, but it wasn't so clean for me, as boost. Both Poco and boost need to be build by you, but if you never used any of them - that is good chance to start, they both are awesome.